# поиск по mysql дереву

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

подскажите как найти в дереве начиная с parent_id=2 все дочерние строки, у которых parent_id нет одинаковых?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. Вы хотите в дереве найти узлы, которые являются единственной дочкой своего ближайшего родителя, что ли? Ну или иными словами - найти всех дочек, которые имеют только одну дочку, и вывести последних.

Comment: В любом случае - это рекурсия. Так что указывайте точно версию сервера - в данном случае это имеет большое значение.

Comment: да, вы правы, нужно вывести все строки у которых одна дочка Сервер: MySQL

Comment: вот такая mysql-5.6.35

Comment: Значит, рекурсия недоступна. Пишите хранимую процедуру.

Comment: на стороне mysql или в php?

Comment: MySQL есссно... разве в PHP есть stored procedures?

Comment: а не подскажите как писать, вернее какой алгоритм использовать, не совсем понимаю как вытащить дочек, у которых одна только дочка

Comment: *какой алгоритм использовать* Создаёшь временную таблицу с уникальным индексом по ID. В неё заносишь (INSERT) начальную запись. Потом в цикле добавляешь в неё записи (INSERT IGNORE), являющиеся дочками хотя бы одной из записей (т.е. связываешь рабочую и временную в качестве источника данных), при этом группируешь по записи рабочей таблицы и считаешь количество дочек. Когда дочки кончатся (HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND) - выбираешь из временной таблицы записи, у родителя которых подсчитанное количество дочек единично. Всё.

Comment: ох ты ж, со стороны не все так легко